# Excel functions in order of memory use/load on the computer?

Tags: excel, performance, optimization, excel-2010, ram

I'm working on (somewhat inherited) some spreadsheets for a coworker that are abysmally designed. I did a quick google search for what I'm asking about but that turned up nothing.

What I'm hoping to find is a list of excel functions (including formulas, perhaps formatting such as hiding and grouping rows and columns, having named ranges, etc) that is ordered in terms of how much stress/ram usage/etc they add to excel by being present in a workbook or worksheet. By this I hope to be able to optimize the books I'm working on somewhat. (it takes a second or two to simply update the text in a cell right now...)

I know that there are also simply design habits that would help such as having calculations laid out in cells from left-to-right but unfortunately things like that I can't change right now.

(hopefully this is on-topic enough for this section....)

Comment: Take a look into [volatile functions](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm).  Some functions calculate every workbook change and some use a smarter recalculation that needs to be done much less often.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Unfortunately that doesn't help my current problem too much as the workbook creator seemed to adore using offsets and fun things like that ;)
However its good to know for future workbooks.

Comment: thats why its so slow though, every time you change a cell every offset recalculates as does every cell that depends on those offset cell values.

Comment: Well yes, and I know thats a large cause of it but I can't re-create all his horrible interlinking workbooks (with MANY sheets in each) in the time I have available. I was hoping for a list of things to see if there were any easy-to-modify things that would make a noticeable impact on the performance.

I don't suppose you know if "grouping" columns/rows together impacts the performance much? Every time I expand or collapse a section it takes a few seconds to figure itself out and its getting annoying. Its probably because of the silly offsets though..

Comment: Conditional formatting can cause issues since it often gets evaluated but other then that I don't think any formatting will have a significant effect on your worksheet compared to a large number of volatile formulas.  You could turn calculations to manual which should speed it up significantly, you just have to remember to calculate before you use any of the numbers.